# ¿En DataAnnotation como le digo que es una vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Normalmente uso esta notación para definir mis tablas

```
namespace domain.Entities
{
     [Table("seg_modulos")]
     public class modulo
     {
          [Column("modID")]
          [Key]
          public int modID { get; set; }

          [Column("modulo")]
          public string modname { get; set; }
     }
}
```

pero el ContextBase me exige por alguna razón que desconosco que tenga una [KEY]
para poder hacer el dbset

```
  public DbSet<modulo> modulo { get; set; }
```

Para efecto de la seguridad en mi sistema quiero llamar una vista, solo hara consultas existe en DataAnotation algun tag como TABLE, View no me funciona, alguien sabe cual es o una forma alterna de hacerlo?

gracias si lo averiguo antes posteo la respuesta un saludo a la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy bien no existe tal cosa como un Data annotationpara vista así que encontré la forma de hacerlo ojo esto para asp core 3.x EF Core.

1) Lo primero porque me da error sino le defino un KEY

```
public DbSet<modulo> modulo { get; set; }
```

porque el EF automáticamente busca un ID así que en las vistas también lo hace y por eso me daba error que no existía un ID.
Entonces lo que tenemos que hacer es lo siguiente:
2) Creamos la entidad sin data annotation

```
namespace domain.Entities
{
     public class permisosview
     {

          public int rolID { get; set; }
          public string rol { get; set; }
          public string modulo { get; set; }
          public int passmodID { get; set; }
          public string submodulo { get; set; }
          public int submodID { get; set; }
          public int passtaskID { get; set; }
          public string tarea { get; set; }

     }
}
```

Luego en el Dbcontext debmos de decirle que es una vista no una tabla y eso lo hacemos modificando el OnModelCreating

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
       modelBuilder
           .Entity<permisosview>(pv =>
           {
                pv.HasNoKey();
                pv.ToView("rol_permisos_view");
                pv.Property(v => v.rolID).HasColumnName("rolID");
                pv.Property(v => v.rol).HasColumnName("rol");
                pv.Property(v => v.modulo).HasColumnName("modulo");
                pv.Property(v => v.passmodID).HasColumnName("passmodID");
                pv.Property(v => v.submodulo).HasColumnName("submodulo");
                pv.Property(v => v.submodID).HasColumnName("submodID");
                pv.Property(v => v.passtaskID).HasColumnName("passtaskID");
                pv.Property(v => v.tarea).HasColumnName("tarea");
           });
  }
```

pueden observar que para la vista "permisosview" no le decimos que no hay key "HasNoKey" y  definimos las columnas y el nombre de la vista en la base de datos. 
ahora podemos facilmente usar el dbset

```
public DbSet<permisosview> permisos { get; set; }
```

y Bueno así usamos vistas con EF Core 3.x para el 2.x es diferente se usa "DbQuery"
Espero a alguien le sirva saludos